# FTP connection issue while upload a file using Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, ftp, connection

I want to upload a file from `Laravel` to another server using `FTP`.

It seems a very simple task, so let's take a look at my configurations:

**.env file**

```
FTP_HOST=dl.myserver.com
FTP_USERNAME=beni@dl.myserver.com
FTP_PASSWORD=somePass
```

**filesystem.php**

```
    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'ftp' => [
            'driver' => 'ftp',
            'host' => env('FTP_HOST'),
            'username' => env('FTP_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('FTP_PASSWORD'),
            'passive'  => true,
            'port' => 21,
            'root' => '/home/myserver/public_html/podcasts'
        ],
       .
       .
       .
```

**and my controller finally**

```
        $year = Carbon::now()->year;
        $month = Carbon::now()->month;
        $day = Carbon::now()->day;

        //podcast
        $podcast = $request->file('podcast');
        $filename = $podcast->getClientOriginalName();
        $purename = substr($filename, 0, strrpos($filename, '.'));


        $filenametostore = $purename . '_' . $year .'_' . $month . '_' . $day . '.' . $podcast->getClientOriginalExtension();

        Storage::disk('ftp')->put($filenametostore, fopen($request->file('podcast'), 'r+'));

.
.
.
```

but I have this error:

> League\Flysystem\ConnectionRuntimeException
>
> Could not log in with connection: dl.myserver.com::21, username:
>   beni@dl.myserver.com

My `FTP` account and information is true because I logged in using `FileZilla`.

As a mention, my `dl.server.com` is using `CPANEL`.

Is there any Idea about this issue?

***Thanks in Advance***

Comment: Nothing jumps out as being wrong in your code to me. Does a connection via sftp over port 22 work? A secure connection might be best anyway, but my first thought here was just to try port 22 if port 21 didn't work.

Comment: Another thought: are you running this inside of a virtual machine? If so, does the virtual machine have access to the server? Maybe there's a network/firewall issue somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly the problem solved when I replaced `env('FTP_HOST')`, `env('FTP_USERNAME')` and `env('FTP_PASSWORD')` with equivalent string values in ***`filesystems.php`*** file!

I tried pure PHP `FTP functions` and figured it out:

```
        $conn_id = ftp_connect("dl.myserver.com");
        ftp_login($conn_id, "beni@dl.myserver.com", "somePass");
        dd(ftp_put($conn_id, $filenametostore, $request->file('podcast'), FTP_ASCII));
```

So my Laravel `filesystem.php` looks like this:

```
        'ftp' => [
            'driver' => 'ftp',
            'host' => "dl.myserver.com", //env('FTP_HOST'),
            'username' => "beni@dl.myserver.com", //env('FTP_USERNAME'),
            'password' => "somePass", //env('FTP_PASSWORD'),
        ],
```

and it works fine in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the password with double quotes in your .env
Particularly if your password contains spaces or #

**FTP_PASSWORD="some#Pass"**